# Check if any item has certain value in an Array

Tags: twig, timber

I try to get a html structure like this

```html
<h2>Next</h2>
<article> First Entry </article>
<article> Second Entry </article>
....
<h2>Previous</h2>
<article> First Entry </article>
<article> Second Entry </article>
...
```

So I check the date with

```
{% for event in events %}
{%- if date(event.band_date) | date('Y-m-d') > 'now' | date('Y-m-d') -%}
Next Stuff
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for event in events %}
{%- if date(event.band_date) | date('Y-m-d') < 'now' | date('Y-m-d') -%}
Previous Stuff
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now I try to figure out how to get the h2 in there, without being in the loop and duplicate itself, plus if there is no entry within the date-range not showing at all.

Comment: Would you mind adding `{% endif %}` and `{% endfor %}` end tags into your code for greater specificity?

Comment: sure, i edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ugly solution would be to use a variable to track whether a heading has been outputted:

```
{% set heading_outputted = false %}
{% for event in events %}
  {% if date(event.band_date)|date('Y-m-d') > 'now'|date('Y-m-d') %}
    {% if not heading_outputted %}
      <h2>Next</h2>
      {% set heading_outputted = true %}
    {% endif %}

    <article>
      {{ event.band }} - {{ event.band_date|date('Y-m-d') }}
    </article>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% set heading_outputted = false %}
{% for event in events %}
  {% if date(event.band_date)|date('Y-m-d') < 'now'|date('Y-m-d') %}
    {% if not heading_outputted %}
      <h2>Previous</h2>
      {% set heading_outputted = true %}
    {% endif %}

    <article>
      {{ event.band }} - {{ event.band_date|date('Y-m-d') }}
    </article>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Example: https://twigfiddle.com/0kdp0u

---

A better solution would be to have the logic in PHP, for example in the controller, or whatever might be the most suitable location in your project. If you pass variables `next_events` and `previous_events` to Twig, the view will be much cleaner:

```
{% if next_events is not empty %}
  <h2>Next</h2>
  {% for event in next_events %}
    <article>
      {{ event.band }} - {{ event.band_date|date('Y-m-d') }}
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if previous_events is not empty %}
  <h2>Previous</h2>
  {% for event in previous_events %}
    <article>
      {{ event.band }} - {{ event.band_date|date('Y-m-d') }}
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Example: https://twigfiddle.com/cvka3g

---

One more solution using the [`filter` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html) and the [loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

```
{% for event in events|filter(event => date(event.band_date)|date('Y-m-d') > 'now'|date('Y-m-d')) %}
  {% if loop.first %}
    <h2>Next</h2>
  {% endif %}

  <article>
    {{ event.band }} - {{ event.band_date|date('Y-m-d') }}
  </article>
{% endfor %}

{% for event in events|filter(event => date(event.band_date)|date('Y-m-d') < 'now'|date('Y-m-d')) %}
  {% if loop.first %}
    <h2>Previous</h2>
  {% endif %}

  <article>
    {{ event.band }} - {{ event.band_date|date('Y-m-d') }}
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

(This solution was inspired by the answer by @Seba.)

Twigfiddle has disabled the `filter` filter for security reasons, so no runnable example for this solution.

Note that the following syntax doesn't work in Twig 3:

```
{% for event in events if date(event.band_date)|date('Y-m-d') > 'now'|date('Y-m-d') %}
  {% if loop.first %}
    <h2>Next</h2>
  {% endif %}

  <article>
    {{ event.band }} - {{ event.band_date|date('Y-m-d') }}
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

It does work in Twig 2 (example: https://twigfiddle.com/zau2sf), but you'll get the following deprecation notice:

> Using an "if" condition on "for" tag in "main.twig" at line 1 is deprecated since Twig 2.10.0, use a "filter" filter or an "if" condition inside the "for" body instead (if your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop).

---

I would personally go with the second solution since the Twig template is the clearest. If that's not possible, I would go with the third solution. The first solution is so messy that I wouldn't choose it.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `<h2>`'s outside of the loop and it will only display once as a header.

```
<h2>Next</h2>
{% for event in events %}
    {%- if date(event.band_date) | date('Y-m-d') > 'now' | date('Y-m-d') -%}
        stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<h2>Previous</h2>
{% for event in events %}
    {%- if date(event.band_date) | date('Y-m-d') < 'now' | date('Y-m-d') -%}
        stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yeah, but I want to check first, if there is even an event with those conditions, else it shouldn't show "next" or "previous"

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it! loop.first did the trick!

```
{% for event in events %}
    {%- if date(event.band_date) | date('Y-m-d') > 'now' | date('Y-m-d') -%}
      {% if loop.first %}
        <h2>Next</h2>
      {% endif %}
      ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If this works for you, it means that the first event in the `events` array belongs to the "next" section, and the code won't work for the "previous" section. Example: https://twigfiddle.com/bxrk3b

Comment: yeah, you're right. It works for me now, if I put the if-statement in the loop itself like `{% for event in events if date(event.band_date) | date('Y-m-d') > 'now' | date('Y-m-d') %}`, but somehow get an syntax error in the fiddle?!

Comment: Are you using Twig 2? I updated my answer with a more thorough reply.

Comment: just realised that Timber uses the version 1.42.5, could update it via composer, probaby gonna do that, thanks a lot!